# Failing service during boot, which one + solution?

Tags: linux-mint, services, ipv6, netfilter

System: [Linux Mint 19.3 "Tricia" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=274), based on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel `5.3.0-24-generic`

---

Problem duration: literally for a year or so.

Problem description: since I have too large a resolution (UHD) on a too small a screen (15.6), I was unable by reading the screen with red FAIL - until now - to find out which service malfunctioned during boot. I have found out by accident by running `systemctl status` to all important services in one sequence.

It appears the `netfilter-persistent.service` fails to boot up for some reason. And I want to know why and how to fix it?

---

Things that might play role here:

### GRUB - IPv6 disabled

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 ..." # the rest is irrelevant here
```

## `iptables-persistent` installed

```
$ apt-cache policy iptables-persistent

iptables-persistent:
  Installed: 1.0.4+nmu2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.0.4+nmu2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.4+nmu2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.4+nmu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have had these two files in place for my firewall configuration to be loaded during boot:

```
/etc/iptables/rules.v4
/etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

---

- Reason for the failure is obvious - the IPv6 protocol is disabled in GRUB.
- Solution is to delete the `rules.v6` now irrelevant file, reboot, and it shall be fine now.

---

```
$ systemctl status netfilter-persistent.service

● netfilter-persistent.service - netfilter persistent configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-12-29 01:51:46 CET; 20min ago
  Process: 944 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 944 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 29 01:51:45 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Dec 29 01:51:45 dell-7577 netfilter-persistent[944]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Dec 29 01:51:46 dell-7577 netfilter-persistent[944]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Dec 29 01:51:46 dell-7577 netfilter-persistent[944]: Warning: skipping IPv6 (no rules to load)
Dec 29 01:51:46 dell-7577 systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
```